# How to properly format time so that it can be displayed correctly when plotting using matplotlib

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, datetime-format

I have data frame with two columns, Time and Values.
Actual values in the Time column are given in the format seconds.milliseconds.
I have created data frame in the following manner:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [1595006371.756430732,1595006372.502789381 ,1595006373.784446912 ,1595006375.476658051], 'Values': [4,5,6,10]},index=list('0123'))
```

I then checked the type of the Time column with

```
test_df.dtypes
```

Time column type is float64.
Then, I converted float64 to datetime64[ns] with

```
test_df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(test_df['Time'], unit='ms')
```

I set the label for Time and plot Values using

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xlabel('Time')
ax=test_df.set_index('Time).plot(lw=3)
```

Time is displayed in the appropriate format hours:minutes:seconds.
Problem is that the values from the Time column are not displayed correctly. In the above example, Time span is inside one second, while the real Time span is several seconds.

When I use the same procedure for the whole data set, I am getting Time span of the to be in seconds, but it should instead be in hours. In other words, by looking at the plot, I would say that elapsed time was several dozens of seconds, instead of several hours as it should be.

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert and store the seconds.millieconds using a converter method. Then you can add to the list and use it in your graph.

```
from pandas import DataFrame


def convert(second, milli_second):
    millis = int(milli_second)
    seconds = (millis/1000) % 60
    seconds = int(seconds) + int(second)
    minutes = (millis/(1000*60)) % 60
    minutes = int(minutes)
    hours = (millis/(1000*60*60)) % 24

    return "%d:%d:%d" % (hours, minutes, seconds)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []
    test_df = DataFrame({'Time': [1595006371.756430732,
                                  1595006372.502789381,
                                  1595006373.784446912,
                                  1595006375.476658051],
                         'Values': [4, 5, 6, 10]}, index=list('0123'))

    for i in test_df['Time']:
        sec, ms = str(i).split('.')
        result = convert(sec, ms)
        results.append(result)

    print(results)
```

Output:

```
['2:6:1595006375', '1:23:1595006419', '0:13:1595006377', '0:7:1595006431']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
If the values in the Time column are given in seconds, is there a way to make this conversion using datetime?